# Camel stopRoute startRoute leaks Thread

Tags: apache-camel

I need to be able to start and stop Routes outside RouteBuilder... So I have a class that monitors external service and switches the route on and off. Basically I want the route to stop consuming new requests and process the current inflight ones.

So I have a scheduled task that runs every x seconds which switches the service on and off. But I found that stopping and starting routes is causing it to Leak Threads.

Basic code :

```
 for(int iCount=0;iCount<10;iCount++) {
   camelContext.stopRoute(TEST_ROUTE);
   camelContext.startRoute(TEST_ROUTE);
 }
```

This seems to create 10 additional Threads. Has anyone come across this before?

NOTE: I have considered using suspend/Resume and also using RoutePolicy. But I would like to know why does Camel leak threads when using Start/Stop route.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I had observed this behavior sometime back where i was periodically doing a stop and start on the routes with 2.9.0 version. I remember reading that this issue was fixed with 2.10.0 or above during my search at that time. I dint get a chance to test it out since my requirement to stop start route periodically wasnt required any more.

Answer (score 0):

When Camel stops a route it uses a background thread to control a graceful shutdown, which you can read about at the Camel website http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html

And when you ask a question on SO then provide more details, for example what is the 10 threads you see? And also what version of Camel you use etc. As well the code for the route you start/stop etc.

Answer (score 0):

[This Camel JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5677) describes the issue you have reported. It would be best to consult the JIRA.